# Inter page communication in asp.net webpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am working on one project in which i want to control webpage which is open in computer browser through mobile web page both pages are in same web site .

When i press "Start" button from mobile then "Start action" should be perform in webpage that is open in my computer .

I think we can use database messaging system for it . but not sure how to achieve this .

Note : In both interface same user will be log in so that we can identify the command for webpage in computer browser .

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand, what your intent is. One "page" can not control another "page", like your scenario suggests. Between two pages is no communication. Since the server delivers the page, it is agnostic to it. The technical term is "stateless". Although there are techniques to circumvent this, namely

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets

or something like that. 
So, if you have some kind of "permanent" connection, something like you intended, would be possible.

Despite, it would be helpful if you further specify, what you intend to do. perhaps there is an "easier" solution, to your problem.

Comment: Java script written in webpage with is looking for command if command is available then if will perform the action according to it . I know http is a stateless protocol but we can use javascript to looking for command every 5 sec .

Comment: So: I am sorry. I did not understand, what your intention was. You are polling a server to look for updates on a state?